# <form> background changes color, dims

Tags: forms, ipad, safari, jquery-validate

I'm experiencing an unusual annoyance. I have a simple form with simple validation attached to it. In iPad's native browser, when I press and hold my finger on the background of the form it changes to a darker color.

This happens only on ipad, with jquery.validate on and the form has to be smaller than the screen size.

Any ideas?

```
$("#ChangePassword").validate({ 
    rules: { 

        OldPassword:{
            required:true
        },
        NewPassword:{
            required:true
        },
        NewPasswordRetype:{
            equalTo: "#NewPassword"
        }
    },
    messages: {

        OldPassword:"&#149; Enter the old password",
        NewPassword:"&#149; Enter the new password",
        NewPasswordRetype:"&#149; Retype the new password"
    }
});


<form id="ChangePassword" method="post"   name="ChangePassword" >
        <div class="field-group">
            <div class="field-row form-item">
                <label class="float-left">Old Password:</label><input name="OldPassword" title="Old Password" type="password" id="OldPassword" size="12" maxlength="12" class="password"><div class="clear"></div>
                <div class="error-container">
                    <!-- <p class="error-message"></p> -->
                </div>
            </div>
          <div class="field-row form-item">
                <label class="float-left">New Password:</label><input name="NewPassword" title="New Password" type="password" id="NewPassword" size="12" maxlength="12" class="password"><div class="clear"></div>
                <div class="error-container">
                    <!-- <p class="error-message"></p> -->
                </div>
            </div>
          <div class="field-row form-item">
                <label class="float-left">Re-type New Password:</label><input name="NewPasswordRetype" title="Retype New Password" type="password" id="NewPasswordRetype" size="12" maxlength="12" class="password"><div class="clear"></div>
                <div class="error-container">
                    <!-- <p class="error-message"></p> -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="button-container">
            <button type="button" name="submit" value="submit" class="css3button-orange" onclick="changePW()" >submit</button>
        </div>

</form>
```